# React-router-dom: Route not displaying expected results

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

js, routing to different modules.

Here is the code:

```
    //Dashboard side bar navigation
const Navigation = () =>{
    return (
        <Navbar className="sidebar">
            <ul className="list-unstyled">
                <li><NavLink to="/dashboard" activeClassName='active' className="nav-link">Dashboard</NavLink></li>

                <li><NavLink to="/become-guide" activeClassName='active' className="nav-link"> Become a Guide</NavLink></li>
            </ul>
        </Navbar>
    )
}

//Admin main screen
const Admin = () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div className="wrapper">
                
                <Navigation />

                <div id="content" className="m-4">
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/dashboard">
                            <Dashboard />
                        </Route>
                        <Route exact path="/become-guide">
                            <BecomeGuide />
                        </Route>
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </BrowserRouter>  
    )
}

export default Admin;
```

And here is the becomeguide.js:

```
//Guide module -navigation
const NavGuide =()=>{
    return(
        <Navbar>
            <Form className="container-fluid justify-content-start">
                <NavLink to="/become-guide/see-all" activeClassName='active'>See All</NavLink>
                <NavLink to="/become-guide/approved" activeClassName='active' >Approved</NavLink>
                <NavLink to="/become-guide/pending" activeClassName='active' >Pending</NavLink>
                <NavLink to="/become-guide/rejected" activeClassName='active' >Rejected</NavLink>
            </Form>
        </Navbar>
    )
}

const GuideSeeAll = ()=> {
    return (
        <div className="bg-dark">Hello See all</div>
    );
}

const GuideApproved = ()=> {
    return (
        <div>Hello Approved</div>
    );
}

const GuidePending = ()=> {
    return (
        <div>Hello Pending</div>
    );
}

const GuideRejected = ()=> {
    return (
        <div>Hello Rejected</div>
    );
}

const BecomeGuide = () =>{
    return (
        
        <Container>
            <Row>
                <NavGuide />
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/become-guide/all">
                            <GuideSeeAll />
                        </Route>
                        <Route exact path="/become-guide/approved">
                            <GuideApproved />
                        </Route>
                        <Route exact path="/become-guide/pending">
                            <GuidePending />
                        </Route>
                        <Route exact path="/become-guide/rejected">
                            <GuideRejected />
                        </Route>
                    </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </Row>
```

Sample Image:

[image: Become Guide link is click]

Sample Image after buttons is clicked:

[image: From Become guide navigation buttons is clicked]

My problem is that, this `becomeguide.js` is from `admin.js` and `becomeguide.js` has it own navigation too, from the when I click the navigation from `becomeguide.js` nothing happens, its will no go to expected view. how can i fix this issue? Thank you!

Comment: hi i suggest you to look at this official react router nesting
https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting
its show a simple way  by I think it will help you solve your problem
and please say which version of react router dom you use there is v6 that some people uses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

1. Using the `exact` prop on the outer base route will necessarily preclude it from matching any sub routes. In other words, since the url path no longer *exactly* matches "/become-guide" when attempting to render a sub-route, i.e. like "/become-guide/see-all", that `BecomeGuide` is unmounted, and thus doesn't/can't render the nested routes.
2. There should be only one router rendering/providing a routing context to the app, so the nested `BrowserRouter` in `BecomeGuide` is unnecessary and is actually blocking the outer router from properly handling the nested routes.

## Solution

Admin - Remove the `exact` prop on any routes rendering subroutes.

```
const Admin = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="wrapper">
                
        <Navigation />

        <div id="content" className="m-4">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/dashboard">
              <Dashboard />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/become-guide">
              <BecomeGuide />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </BrowserRouter>  
  )
}
```

BecomeGuide - Remove the nested router. You can also probably remove the `exact` prop on these routes as well since they all have the same path specificity for matching.

```
<Row>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/become-guide/all">
      <GuideSeeAll />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/become-guide/approved">
      <GuideApproved />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/become-guide/pending">
      <GuidePending />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/become-guide/rejected">
      <GuideRejected />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</Row>
```